# How To add Cross-Compiled Kernel Objects to Yocto Build

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, imx8

I am trying to port 88w8987 based wifi/bt modem for my custom board with iMX8MP. I've cross compiled the firmware and generated the related object files. My question is how can I add these files to final image created by yocto project so I can probe the drivers? For now, board is only has a USB connection configured as USB Host which I am using for flashing the board on serial download mode.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a recipe and inherit the [module class](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#ref-classes-module), to install .ko files correctly.